# Page breaks and headings in long table or grid

Tags: output-formatting, grid-layouts

I have a need for long tables in a document I am producing but I am having difficulty. The printed document ends up with page breaks midway through the table which cuts rows part way through.
I'd also like to have the table headings printed at the start of the new page when tables span multiple pages.

Is there a simple solution to this problem or does it require a solution that involves calculating line breaks and building multiple tables?

The example code will produce a nice table and if you print preview the output from this code you will see what I mean.

```
dogs = EntityValue[Entity["DogBreed"], {"Name", "Origin", "Temperament","LifeSpan"}];
tableText = Join[{{"Name", "Origin", "Temperament", "LifeSpan"}}, RandomSample[dogs, 100]];

Text[Grid[tableText, Frame -> All,
    ItemStyle -> {{{{FontSize -> 10, LineIndent -> 0}}}, {{{Bold, White}}, {{Plain, Black}}}}, 
    ItemSize -> {{12, 12, 25, 10}},  Alignment -> Center, Spacings -> 0,
    Background -> {None, {Black, {GrayLevel[0.7], LightGray}}}]]
```

The resultant table looks like this:
[image: First few entries of formatted table]

The effect at a page break looks like this:
[image: Table at a page break]